# Calculating Entropy

Tags: r, frequency, entropy

I've tried for several hours to calculate the Entropy and I know I'm missing something. Hopefully someone here can give me an idea!

EDIT: I think my formula is wrong!

**CODE:**

```
 info <- function(CLASS.FREQ){
      freq.class <- CLASS.FREQ
      info <- 0
      for(i in 1:length(freq.class)){
        if(freq.class[[i]] != 0){ # zero check in class
          entropy <- -sum(freq.class[[i]] * log2(freq.class[[i]]))  #I calculate the entropy for each class i here
        }else{ 
          entropy <- 0
        } 
        info <- info + entropy # sum up entropy from all classes
      }
      return(info)
    }
```

I hope my post is clear, since it's the first time I actually post here.

**This is my dataset:**

```
buys <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no")

credit <- c("fair", "excellent", "fair", "fair", "fair", "excellent", "excellent", "fair", "fair", "fair", "excellent", "excellent", "fair", "excellent")

student <- c("no", "no", "no","no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")

income <- c("high", "high", "high", "medium", "low", "low", "low", "medium", "low", "medium", "medium", "medium", "high", "medium")

age <- c(25, 27, 35, 41, 48, 42, 36, 29, 26, 45, 23, 33, 37, 44) # we change the age from categorical to numeric
```

Comment: Ironically of course, the worse the calculation, the closer the answer.

Comment: It would be good to post (a) the formula you think is right, and (b) a sample of the type of data you will feed to this function. Using `dput()` is a great way to share data.

Comment: And the answer should be: 0.940286.

Comment: @Codex, which object is that answer referring to (e.g. age? income?) or are you trying to combine all objects?  Quickly running through some, it appears to refer to 'buys'?

Comment: @cdeterman It is not specified in the answer what exactly the answer is referring to, that's why I'm so frustrated. But my thoughts are either "buys" since its the class label or alternatively all objects combined.

Comment: @cdeterman, How are you actually running through them? I think i'm failing/misunderstanding that part.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ultimately I find no error in your code as it runs without error.  The part I think you are missing is the calculation of the class frequencies and you will get your answer.  Quickly running through the different objects you provide I suspect you are looking at `buys`.

```
buys <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no")
freqs <- table(buys)/length(buys)
info(freqs)
[1] 0.940286
```

As a matter of improving your code, you can simplify this dramatically as you don't need a loop if you are provided a vector of class frequencies.

For example:

```
# calculate shannon-entropy
-sum(freqs * log2(freqs))
[1] 0.940286
```

As a  side note, the function `entropy.empirical` is in the `entropy` package where you set the units to log2 allowing some more flexibility.  Example:

```
entropy.empirical(freqs, unit="log2")
[1] 0.940286
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an another way similar to above answer but using a different function.

```
> buys <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no")

> probabilities <- prop.table(table(buys))

> probabilities
buys
       no       yes 
0.3571429 0.6428571 

> -sum(probabilities*log2(probabilities))

[1] 0.940286
```

Also there is a built in function `entropy.empirical(probabilities, unit = "log2")`